# Update column values for given index pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, series

Not able to update column values for a dataframe for given index even though no error ?

```
import pandas as pd

dict = {'col_1': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C'},
         'col_2': {0: 'I', 1: 'J', 2: 'K'},
         }
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
my_index = [1,2]
df['col_3'] = None
df.loc[my_index, :].col_3 = 'X'
```

Current Output (df)

```
  col_1  col_2  col_3
0   A     I     None
1   B     J     None
2   C     K     None
```

Expected Output (df)

```
  col_1  col_2  col_3
0   A     I     None
1   B     J     X
2   C     K     X
```

Comment: I think you meant `df.loc[my_index, 'col_3'] = 'X'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try

```
df.loc[my_index, 'col_3'] = 'X'
df
Out[14]: 
  col_1 col_2 col_3
0     A     I  None
1     B     J     X
2     C     K     X
```

Comment: Oh nice!.  surprise to found df.loc[my_index, :].col_3 & df.loc[my_index, 'col_3'] returns same series , but assignment working differently